# Use timers to change UI

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, timer, swt

I was trying to make a simple clock that updates once every second so as to lower the cost on the CPU. I originally tried using `Thread.sleep()`, but when used within a loop in a GUI it essentially froze the whole thing and caused it to crash, though without any particular error shown in the console.

I looked up other ways to send commands at specific intervals and came across the `Timer` so I tried using that. Right now I have this code.

```
package clock;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;

public class SystemClock {
    Text labelHours;
    Text labelMinutes;
    Text labelSeconds;
    Text labelMeridian;
    TimerTask time = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            pullClock();
        }
    };
    boolean pause=false;
    Timer play = new Timer();
    long delay = 1000;
    long period = 1000;
    protected Shell shlClock;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SystemClock window = new SystemClock();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlClock.open();
        shlClock.layout();
        while (!shlClock.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shlClock = new Shell();
        shlClock.setSize(205, 118);
        shlClock.setText("Clock");
        shlClock.setLayout(null);

        Label labelColonHoursMinutes = new Label(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelColonHoursMinutes.setBounds(64, 10, 9, 15);
        labelColonHoursMinutes.setText(":");

        Label labelColonMinutesSeconds = new Label(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelColonMinutesSeconds.setBounds(96, 10, 9, 15);
        labelColonMinutesSeconds.setText(":");

        labelMinutes = new Text(shlClock, SWT.NONE | SWT.CENTER);
        labelMinutes.setBounds(71, 10, 19, 15);
        labelMinutes.setEditable(false);
        labelMinutes.setText("00");

        labelHours = new Text(shlClock, SWT.NONE | SWT.CENTER);
        labelHours.setEditable(false);
        labelHours.setBounds(40, 10, 18, 15);
        labelHours.setText("00");

        labelSeconds = new Text(shlClock, SWT.NONE | SWT.CENTER);
        labelSeconds.setBounds(101, 10, 25, 15);
        labelSeconds.setEditable(false);
        labelSeconds.setText("00");

        Button btnRefresh = new Button(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        btnRefresh.setBounds(58, 36, 75, 25);
        btnRefresh.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    pause= !pause;
                    if (pause)
                        try{
                            play.scheduleAtFixedRate(time, delay, period);
                        }catch(Exception ex){

                        }
                    else
                        play.cancel();
                }
        });
        btnRefresh.setText("Pause/Play");

        labelMeridian = new Text(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelMeridian.setBounds(125, 10, 25, 15);
        labelMeridian.setEditable(false);
        labelMeridian.setText("AM");

    }


public void pullClock(){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
        String hoursStr;
        String minutesStr;
        String secondsStr;
        String meridian;            
            currentTime/=1000;
            seconds = (int)currentTime%60;
            currentTime/=60;
            minutes = (int)currentTime%60;
            currentTime/=60;
            hours = (int)currentTime%24;
            hours -=4;

            switch(hours){
                case -4: hoursStr="8"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case -3: hoursStr="9"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case -2: hoursStr="10"; meridian = "PM"; break; 
                case -1: hoursStr="11"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case  0: hoursStr="12"; meridian = "AM"; break;
                case 12: hoursStr="12"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 13: hoursStr="1"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 14: hoursStr="2"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 15: hoursStr="3"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 16: hoursStr="4"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 17: hoursStr="5"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 18: hoursStr="6"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 19: hoursStr="7"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                default: hoursStr=String.valueOf(hours); meridian = "AM";
            }
            secondsStr=String.valueOf(seconds);
            minutesStr=String.valueOf(minutes);
            labelHours.setText(hoursStr);
            labelMinutes.setText((minutes<10) ? "0"+minutesStr:minutesStr);
            labelSeconds.setText((seconds<10) ? "0"+secondsStr:secondsStr);
            labelMeridian.setText(meridian);
        }
    }
```

This results in `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException` and crashes the program.

I'm using Eclipse and it's easily obtainable SWT gui editor to build the program and it seems to be part of the problem. My question essentially is if there is a way to fix it while still using SWT, and if not would this work if I used `JFrame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Display#timerExec()` in SWT. The method accepts a runnable that it will execute once after a given amount of miliseconds have passed.

```
display.timerExec( 1000, new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if( !shlClock.isDisposed() {
      pullClock();
      display.timerExec( 1000, this );
    }
  }
}
```

In the snippet above, the runnable re-schedules itslef (`display.timerExec( 1000, this );`) when the actual work was done.

In order to cancel an already scheduled runnable, call `display.timerExec( -1, runnable )`.

Comment: This does almost what I was hoping for. Only thing that I still need it to do is be able to pause it if necessary. How would you go about pausing timerExec like this so that it would not infinitely repeat?

Comment: `timerExec()` executes the given runnable **just once**. The _infinity_ is caused by the runnable that re-schedules itslef with `display.timerExec( 1000, this );`. Simply omit the 'inner' `timerExec()` call to pause. See also the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. Specifically, the ability to cancel the task after it was already scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

Using `display.timerExec` as mentioned in the other answer is probably best, but you can also use `Display.syncExec` in the timer task:

```
TimerTask time = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Display.getDefault().synchExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              pullClock();
           }
        });
    }
};
```

or if you are using Java 8 you can simplify this as:

```
TimerTask time = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Display.getDefault().synchExec(() -> pullClock());
    }
};
```